# Get Picture from Client - save on MongoDB, expressJS, nodeJS

Tags: image, node.js, mongodb, express, upload

I'm trying to Implement a simple Picture upload from the client to my mongoDB.
I've read many explanations but I can't find a way from start to finish.

My clientside -

```
function profilePic(input) {
    if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
        var file = input.files[0];
        localStorage.setItem('picture', JSON.stringify(file));
    }

}
```

Later on I take the this JSON from the LocalStorage and send it to my server side like this:

```
    var request = false;
    var result = null;
    request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    if (request) {
        request.open("POST", "usersEditProf/");
        request.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (request.readyState == 4 && request.status == 200) {
                .....//More code to send to Server
        request.setRequestHeader('content-type', 'application/json');
        request.send(JSON.stringify(localStorage.getItem('picture)));
    }
}
```

On my serverside:

```
        app.post('/usersEditProf/',users.editProfile);
    /** Edits the Profile - sends the new one **/
    exports.editProfile = function(req, res) {
     var toEdit = req.body;
     var newPic = toEdit.picture;
```

And thats where I get lost. is `newPic` actually holding the picture? I doubt it...
Do I need to change the path? What is the new path I need to give the picture?
How do I put it in my DB? Do I need GridFS?

When trying to simply put that in my collection, it looks like this (example with a image called bar.jpg:

```
 picture: "{\"webkitRelativePath\":\"\",\"lastModifiedDate\":\"2012-10-08T23:34:50.000Z\",\"name\":\"bar.jpg\",\"type\":\"image/jpeg\",\"size\":88929}",
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to upload a blob through XMLHTTPRequest(), you need to use an HTML 5 FormData object:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData

It alows you to specify a filename to push, then you handle the incoming file as you would with a mime form post. Note the limitations on browser support when you use the FormData object. Your alternative is a form POST to a hidden frame, which works OK but is not nearly as clean looking in code as FormData.

Comment: Thanks - but all the strings I've passed so far didn't require me to use FormData, but a file does require this?

Comment: @orepor, sorry for the delay, the FormData object is the only way to POST a file through AJAX. Otherwise you are stuck using the old method (hidden frame) or using a Flash-based file upload control like you can build with Apache Flex.